# Simulate Amazon Kindle in a virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, kindle

I would like to simulate an Amazon kindle in a VM.

Is there a way to simulate a Kindle on my computer, so I can see how my created books would look on a Kindle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the e-ink Kindles, [Amazon Previewer (available for both Windows on Mac)](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000765261) will do what you want. Here's a list of its features, and there are more FAQs on the site.

```
* Highlights of Kindle Previewer functionality
* Ability to preview your content across Kindle devices and apps
* Support for previewing Kindle Text Pop Ups and Kindle Panel Views
* Accurate rendering of your content across Kindle devices and apps
* Faster previewing through features like Auto flip mode, Image flip mode
* Auto updates for future enhancements
```

Answer (score 1):

not in virtual machine by there is an android development environment.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

and you use the amazon SDK from here

https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/01-setting-up-your-development-environment

Answer (score -1):

You need it to get a real download of your book I understand. So far no one built a VM Eink yet. For those not in the know since January 2023 kindle does not download newer books. Making censorship a real issue. Meaning Amerzon can Delete or Edit none woke books you paid for remotely. But the policy not binding on Older Eink devices on kindle firmware lower than Version 5.10.2. So that's the only way to get and backup a Digital version of your book.